# returning List<String> from a Rest webservice

Tags: java, rest

Iam learning REST webservice. I have written a very basic code to return a List from the webservice. below is code snippet

```
@Path("hello")
public class Hello {


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public List<String> greeting() {

        List<String> greeting = new ArrayList<>();
        greeting.add("Hello World");
        greeting.add("How are you");
        greeting.add("Hope you are doing good");
        greeting.add("Hey WhatsApp");
        greeting.add("Take care");
        greeting.add("Perform well");


        return greeting;
    }

}
```

the messagebodywriter implementation is below

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class ListMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<List<String>>{

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {        
        System.out.println("here in the isWriteable");

        return type == List.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(List<String> t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        System.out.println("here in the writeTo");
        System.out.println("t="+t);
        System.out.println("size of t "+t.size());

        Writer writer = new PrintWriter(entityStream);
        writer.write("list of string will be returned later");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    }
```

But when i run the code i still get the same error as below

**MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/plain, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List.**

Why iam getting the same error despite implementing the messagebodywriter?

Comment: please edit the question and show more of the error stack calls

Comment: Thats the only error line iam getting..do you think my messagebodywriter implementation is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {        
        System.out.println("here in the isWriteable");

        return type == List.class;
    }
```

changing the **return type == List.class;**  to

**return type == ArrayList.class;**
solved the error.